# TSQL: Find Groups of Records in a Sequence of Records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

Sorry for the title if you find it incorrect, I *really* wasn't sure how to name this question. There is probably a term for this type of query/pattern.

I have a sequence of records that need to be ordered by date, the records have a condition I would like to "group" by (SomeCondition) to get the earliest start date and latest end date (taking NULL's into account) but I'm unsure how to accomplish the query (if it's even possible). The original records in the table look something like;

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| AbcID | XyzID | StartDate  | EndDate    | SomeCondition |
-----------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | 1     | 2018-01-01 | 2018-03-05 | 1             |
| 2     | 1     | 2018-04-20 | 2018-05-01 | 1             |
| 3     | 1     | 2018-05-02 | 2018-05-15 | 0             |
| 4     | 1     | 2018-06-01 | 2018-07-01 | 1             |
| 5     | 1     | 2018-08-01 | NULL       | 1             |
| 6     | 2     | 2018-01-01 | 2018-06-30 | 1             |
| 7     | 2     | 2018-07-01 | 2018-08-31 | 0             |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

The result I'm going for would be;

```
-----------------------------------
| XyzID | StartDate  | EndDate    |
-----------------------------------
| 1     | 2018-01-01 | 2018-05-01 |
| 1     | 2018-06-01 | NULL       |
| 2     | 2018-01-01 | 2018-06-30 |
-----------------------------------
```

Thanks for any help/insight, even if it's "not possible".

Comment: This is a type of "Gaps and Islands Problem".    Google that term and see if you find anything that helps you.

Comment: I'm unsure how to answer your question, because I can't figure out the logic you used to generate the expected output.  If you want to get help here, I'd recommend explaining your query.

Comment: Will you please check your output table, may be your output first row contain 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 2018-07-01 00:00:00.000 information. May be this query(select XyzID,SomeCondition,Min(StartDate) StartDate,MAX(EndDate) EndDate from test group by SomeCondition,XyzID) help you.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Tab's "Gaps and Islands Problem" is exactly what I was going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this problem requires you to solve it piece by piece. Here are the steps that I used to do that:

1. Determine when the island begins (when `SomeCondition` is false)
2. Create an "ID" number for each island (within each `XyzID`) by summing the number of `IslandBegin`s while considering the records in `AbcID` order
3. Determine the first and last `AbcID` within each `XyzID`/`IslandNumber` combination where `SomeCondition` is true
4. Use the previous step as a guide as to what `StartDate` / `EndDate` you should get for each record in the result set

**Sample Data:**

```
declare @sample_data table
    (
        AbcID int
        , XyzID int
        , StartDate date
        , EndDate date
        , SomeCondition bit
    )

insert into @sample_data
values (1, 1, '2018-01-01', '2018-03-05', 1)             
    , (2, 1, '2018-04-20', '2018-05-01', 1)             
    , (3, 1, '2018-05-02', '2018-05-15', 0)             
    , (4, 1, '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', 1)             
    , (5, 1, '2018-08-01', NULL, 1)             
    , (6, 2, '2018-01-01', '2018-06-30', 1)             
    , (7, 2, '2018-07-01', '2018-08-31', 0)
```

**Answer:**

The comments in the code show which step each part of the [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is accomplishing.

```
with island_bgn as
    (
        --Step 1
        select d.AbcID
        , d.XyzID
        , d.StartDate
        , d.EndDate
        , d.SomeCondition
        , case when d.SomeCondition = 0 then 1 else 0 end as IslandBegin
        from @sample_data as d  
    )
    , island_nbr as
    (
        --Step 2
        select b.AbcID
        , b.XyzID
        , b.StartDate
        , b.EndDate
        , b.SomeCondition
        , b.IslandBegin
        , sum(b.IslandBegin) over (partition by b.XyzID order by b.AbcID asc) as IslandNumber
        from island_bgn as b    
    )
    , prelim as
    (
        --Step 3
        select n.XyzID
        , n.IslandNumber
        , min(n.AbcID) as AbcIDMin
        , max(n.AbcID) as AbcIDMax
        from island_nbr as n
        where 1=1
        and n.SomeCondition = 1
        group by n.XyzID
        , n.IslandNumber    
    )
--Step 4
select p.XyzID
, a.StartDate
, b.EndDate
from prelim as p
inner join @sample_data as a on p.AbcIDMin = a.AbcID
inner join @sample_data as b on p.AbcIDMax = b.AbcID
order by p.XyzID
, a.StartDate
, b.EndDate
```

**Results:**

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| XyzID | StartDate  | EndDate    |
+-------+------------+------------+
| 1     | 2018-01-01 | 2018-05-01 |
+-------+------------+------------+
| 1     | 2018-06-01 | NULL       |
+-------+------------+------------+
| 2     | 2018-01-01 | 2018-06-30 |
+-------+------------+------------+
```